# How can I select an element only if it doesn't have a class assigned?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm modifying the CSS of an existing WordPress theme. The theme has a lot of special styles for lists, attached to the `<li>` element. Because of this, there is a generic `list-style:none` rule applied to the `<li>` element.

I want to update the CSS to reinstitute the `list-style` defaults on `<li>` elements that don't have a class attached (i.e. those that don't have a special style applied). This needs to be selective to keep from ruining the fancy effects.

I am aware of the :not() pseudo-selector, and may end up using it to specifically exclude each possible class; however, there are a dozen of them and this seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Is there any way, either using CSS or jQuery, to select an element by specifying that it has *no* class set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery: `$('li[class=]')` (selects both elements that have no class attribute as well as those for which the attribute is present, but empty)

The CSS selector `li[class=""]` unfortunately does not work the same way. It selects only those elements for which the attribute is present, but empty (ex: `<li class></li>` or `<li class=""></li>`)

The `$('li:not([class])')` solution might not be what you want (it doesn't select elements that have the class attribute present but empty).

Given:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li class>item 2</li>
  <li class="">item 3</li>
  <li class="some-class">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

`$('li[class=]')` selects 1,2,3
`$('li[class=""]')` selects 2,3
`$('li:not([class])')` selects just 1

Comment: Thanks for including examples. That makes the differences between the selectors very clear.

Answer (score 8):

`$('li:not([class])');` should do what you need.

Considering Dan's comment - since you didn't specify I assumed you meant the `li` would have no `class` attribute at all. If you need to grab those that are `<li class>` or `<li class="">`...

```
$('li:not([class])');
$('li[class=]');
$('li[class=""]');
```

Comment: Does not select elements like: `<li class></li>` or `<li class=""></li>`

Comment: You're correct; I was thinking of `<li>`, with no class attribute at all. I appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, you can do it:

```
$('li[class=]')
```

or

```
$('li:not([class]=)')
```

K