# checking if element with class exists

Tags: jquery

```
var currentClassName = $(this).parent('td').next('td').find('input:text').attr('class');

                if (currentClassName == undefined) {
                    currentClassName = $(this).parent('td').find('input:text').attr('class');
                }
```

This works, but i suppose it can be written in one row? Im not really satisfied with this solution. Thanks

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941247/how-can-i-select-an-element-only-if-it-doesnt-have-a-class-assigned) should be able to answer your question.

Comment: There maybe a better option, but it's very unclear what you are actually trying to achieve here. Are you trying to get the class of the `input` in a neighboring `td, but if there isn't one get the class of the input in the same `td`? It would really help if you described the bigger picture. How does the HTML look like? What is `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentClassName = $(this).parent('td').next('td').find('input:text').attr('class');
currentClassName = (currentClassName == undefined ? $(this).parent('td').find('input:text').attr('class') : currentClassName);
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to get rid of the undefined check, maybe itisnt possible..

Comment: Well, the very essence of what you're doing here is to check if an element has any class, and if it doesn't, take the class of another element. The undefined-check is pretty essential to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(#elm).is('.classname')) {
//#elm has the class
} else {
//#elm doesn't have the class
}
```

Comment: I think the OP does not know the className in advance. But you can use .hasClass('classname') instead of .is

Comment: Oops, got confused with question

Comment: shouldnt hasClass method be used in your example? :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you should be able to check the existence of a class using the attribute jQuery selector:

```
if ($(this).parent('td').next('td').find('input:text[class]').length != 0) {

  // do something

}
```

Comment: My method for checking the existence of a class is working as well. what im looking for is a solution one one row (without the shorthand if). but i guess it might not be possible